# What are the best-practices for validating phone records?

Tags: statistical-significance, dataset, trend, anomaly-detection, quality-control

I have a bunch of telephone data including information on call start time, end time, and duration. I am trying to evaluate the quality of the dataset to determine if the phone call data are legitimate or manufactured. What are the best-practices in evaluating a dataset like this? What tools can I use to perform a task like this? Bonus points if there are publications on this topic!

Comment: Ideally you would have a labelled training dataset to learn the characteristics of legitimate and manufactured data - do you have that? Without any data to suggest what differentiates the two, you're left with either domain knowledge, or unsupervised methods which may or may not group samples by the characteristic you want (nor would you be able to tell how well it did).

Answer (score 1):

Per Nuclear Hoagie's comment, if you have a labeled training data set a machine learning/classification approach may be possible. Otherwise, I'd start by visualizing the data.

If times are recorded to the second (or even more precisely) it's probably reasonable to expect terminal digits to be uniformly distributed. There's a lot of literature on this as a test of data quality applied to different applications. So that's one place to start. Here are a few references:

- Rath, G. J. (1966). Randomization by Humans. The American Journal of Psychology, 79(1), 97–103. https://doi.org/10.2307/1420712
- Schulz, M. A., Schmalbach, B., Brugger, P., & Witt, K. (2012). Analysing humanly generated random number sequences: a pattern-based approach. PloS one, 7(7), e41531. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0041531

Another approach would be to look for duplicates. This can also be a marker of fabricated data. Here's a relevant paper related to surveys:

- Kuriakose, N., & Robbins, M. (2016). Don't get duped: Fraud through
  duplication in public opinion surveys. Statistical Journal of the
  IAOS, 32(3), 283-291. https://doi.org/10.3233/SJI-160978

I suspect there's also some reasonable assumptions about call times, etc. Visualizing this could be a good starting place and then perhaps you can supplement this with domain knowledge, e.g. I would expect much higher call frequencies at 2:00 p.m. than 2:00 a.m.

Finally, you might want to try ascertain if the data looks too neat such that it might have been generated by a random sample of a particular distribution. [This example](http://datacolada.org/98) from Datacoloda might be helpful.